# Content Editor Web Part Uneditable in IE9

Tags: wss-3.0, content-editor-web-part, internet-explorer

A user added a content editor web part with just some simple HTML formatted text to it today. Once the text is added and the page is saved no body can seem to edit the web part's properties unless they use designer or Chrome/FireFox. I find that a bit ironic... But anyway, I have tried IE compatibility settings back to IE7 with no change in the behavior. This has worked in the past, I was mostly wondering if anyone has experienced this recently and if so, were you able to correct it? We have tried this with four different systems, all running IE9 one is not domain joined and the site is in the trusted sites list.

Comment: Does it make a difference whether you insert the html directly into the web part or reference an html file?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? Foundation or Server? Area you having some customizations such an own master page etc. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user had created the HTML in the web part using the built in Rich Text editor. It had created invalid HTML that was then interfering with the web part's JavaScript in IE. The web part continued to work in Chome and FireFox as I mentioned.

Unfortunately I was only concerned with getting it to work and I copied the HTML into NotePad++ and removed all of the additional blank DIV tags and even some XSLT that should not have been there. Once I did all that it worked. I should have taken the time to actually find out what was causing the problem. Sorry I was not a little more diligent. I suspect it was the XSLT.